# How to sort RDD

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark, rdd

I have scoreTriplets is RDD[ARRAY[String]] which I am sorting by following way.

```
var ScoreTripletsArray = scoreTriplets.collect()
  if (ScoreTripletsArray.size > 0) {        
    /*Sort the ScoreTripletsArray descending by score field*/        
    scala.util.Sorting.stableSort(ScoreTripletsArray, (e1: Array[String], e2: Array[String]) => e1(3).toInt > e2(3).toInt)
}
```

But collect() will be heavy If there is elements in lack.

So I need to sort RDD by `score` without using collect().
scoreTriples is RDD[ARRAY[String]] each line of RDD will store Array of the below variables.
EdgeId sourceID destID `score` sourceNAme destNAme distance

Please give me any reference or hint.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorting will be, due to shuffling, an expensive operation even without collecting but you can use `sortBy` method:

```
import scala.util.Random

val data = Seq.fill(10)(Array.fill(3)("") :+ Random.nextInt.toString)
val rdd  = sc.parallelize(data)

val sorted = rdd.sortBy(_.apply(3).toInt)
sorted.take(3)
// Array[Array[String]] = Array(
//   Array("", "", "", -1660860558),
//   Array("", "", "", -1643214719),
//   Array("", "", "", -1206834289))
```

If you're interested only in the top results then `top` and `takeOrdered` are usually preferred.

```
import scala.math.Ordering

rdd.takeOrdered(2)(Ordering.by[Array[String], Int](_.apply(3).toInt))
// Array[Array[String]] = 
//   Array(Array("", "", "", -1660860558), Array("", "", "", -1643214719))

rdd.top(2)(Ordering.by[Array[String], Int](_.apply(3).toInt))
// Array[Array[String]] = 
//   Array(Array("", "", "", 1920955686), Array("", "", "", 1597012602))
```

Comment: but i have one issue.. I need to convert rdd in to array then. .how can i do this? because my remaining code is dependent on array.

Comment: If you want all data the only way is to collect. `top` and `takeOrdered` already returns an array.

Comment: can i use like `rdd.top(rdd.count())(Ordering.by[Array[String], Int](_.apply(3).toInt))` So i can get all data

Comment: It doesn't make sense. `top` / `takeOrdered` are superior only if you need only a small part of data. Otherwise `sortBy` followed by `collect` is the right way to go.

Comment: ok.. but `sortBy` followed by `collect` will return array? or how?

Comment: Yes, it will return an array.

Comment: Ok.. thanks a lot.. last question.. I have 3 lack node and `collect` will cost me in term of memory.. will it possible to use `sortBy` without `collect` and still return `Array`.

Comment: It means all data has to fit in a driver memory. One way or another array is a local data structure. You can always [ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and describe what you do with collected results. Maybe it is possible  without using local array / fetching data to driver.

Answer (score 3):

There is sortBy method in RDD (see [doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)).
You can do something like that

```
scoreTriplets.sortBy( _(3).toInt )
```