# Get the last 5 lines of a 1000 line csv, RDD Spark Java

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, rdd

I have a .csv file that has 1000 lines of data in it, and I'm trying to write a line of code that will show only the last 5 lines of data.

```
private SparkSession spark;
    private JavaSparkContext sc;
    private JavaRDD<String> lines;
    private JavaRDD<PurchaseOrder> orders;


public OrderProcessingRDDSparkApp(String ...args) throws IOException {
        spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("OrderProcessingSparkApp").config("spark.master", "local[1]").getOrCreate();
        sc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());
        sc.setLogLevel("ERROR");        
        lines = sc.textFile(args[0]);
        orders = lines.map( line -> new PurchaseOrder(line));
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Are you reading in a text file or csv with ```sc.textFile(args[0])```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```scala
    import scala.util.Random    
    val sorted = rdd.sortBy(_.apply(3).toInt) //sort asc or desc...
    sorted.take(5) //get last 5...
```

You can have this approach using Java.

Possibly a [[duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33774830/how-to-sort-rdd)